# Refresh height after resizing with js

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, resize

I have a nice script which let 2 divs have equill height.
but after I resize my browser the height keeps the same while I need it to be responsive and refreshes.

Really have no idea how to do this.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var height = Math.max($(".h-txt.left").height(), $(".h-img.right").height());
        $(".h-txt.left").height(height);
        $(".h-img.right").height(height);
    });
```

Do I need to add a "document on refresh / resize" function?

Comment: I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/kyus8k73/

Comment: `window.resize()` is the one you need

Comment: something likle this? $(document)window.resize() {..}

Comment: actually more like this: `$(window).resize(function(){ ... });`

Comment: why peoples downvote my question.. whatever

Comment: Because a simple google search would have shown you thousands of answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    $(".h-txt, .h-img").css("height", "auto");
    var height = Math.max($(".h-txt.left").height(), $(".h-img.right").height());
    $(".h-txt.left").height(height);
    $(".h-img.right").height(height);
});

$(window).trigger("resize");
```

First we're resetting height to "auto" to make sure we always get height of the higher of the two `<div>`s later on.

Then - we actually get the height of the bigger one, and force it onto both elements.

Whole cycle repeats each time the window is resized - our function is bound to the "resize" event of the window. (`$(window).resize(...);`)

Last line is just triggering it on the initial load of the page, so we won't have to actually resize the window to get it launched for the first time.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5z0ett7e/

Comment: thanks m8 this works like a charm :) http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/kyus8k73/2/ will check this as awnser in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your code into a function, and call it with '.resize()'

```
    var responsiveSize = function() {
      var height = Math.max($(".h-txt.left").height(), $(".h-img.right").height());
      $(".h-txt.left").height(height);
      $(".h-img.right").height(height);
    }
    // This will call it on page load
    responsiveSize();

    // This will call it on window resize
    $(window).resize(function(){ 
     responsiveSize();
    });
```

Comment: You still need to keep the code within a jquery ready function

Comment: Just as a note: you don't need to introduce an additional anonymous function for the resize, you could just write: `$(window).resize( responsiveSize )`. Additionally you could also make a regular named function `function responsiveSize() {  .... }`. It does not make a real difference in functionality, but it is just a not needed _complexity_.